# Current flow through car struck by lightning

Tags: electrostatics

It is safe to sit under a car rather than to stand under a tree during lightning.
The electric field inside the car is zero when the lightning falls on it so, after falling on car, where do the charges go?

Comment: What does conservation of charge has to do with the tree and safety? You should start with some simple Wiki research and improve your question a little bit. Under the car is probably very very unsafe; inside the car is the place to be.

Comment: Mohd, I've suggested a better title for the question. If you don't like the change please feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 3):

> It is safe to sit under a car rather than to stand under a tree during lightening

It is safe so sit **inside** a car during a thunderstorm, but I don't think sitting **under** a car is a good idea.

The car behaves as two resistors in series. The car body has a very low resistance (assuming it's metal bodied) so the current flows through the car body with very little voltage drop. The current then has to flow to the ground through the tyres, and because tyres are very poor conductors the majority of voltage drop occurs over the tyres. If there is a better conductor between the floor panel of the car and the ground the current will flow through that instead. If that better conductor is you, well, you just got fried.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning strikes on cars are less documented than strikes on aircraft which are also a market for lightning protection, so well-researched. Check the film here
http://wxguard.com/latest-lightning-news/aircraft-struck-in-flight

It seems risky to say

> The electric field inside the car is zero when the lightning falls on it

because the "Faraday cage" effect could be imperfect with insulating windows, synthetic body parts, and imperfect conduction by metallic parts some of which are insulated from each other (radio antennae). To a lesser extent, induced currents would also be possible.

To get better answers than this, why not replace the passenger **under** a car in your question with a passenger **in** a plane ?